# SCons as an egg in zc.buildout

Tags: scons, buildout

Is there an easy way to install SCons as an egg using zc.buildout? My initial thought was that since it uses distutils I would be able to install it using zc.recipe.egg and thought that the egg would be set up in such a way that the SCons scripts go to ${buildout:directory}/bin and SCons gets added to the PYTHONPATH.

```
[buildout]
parts = 
    python

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = mython
eggs = 
    SCons == 2.0.1
```

Unfortunately, I don't think SCons' setup.py is written in such a way that it works well with zc.recipe.egg. I end up with:

1. ${buildout:directory}/eggs/scons-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/
2. ${buildout:directory}/eggs/scons-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/scons-2.0.1/
3. ${buildout:directory}/eggs/scons-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/scons-2.0.1/SCons/
4. ${buildout:directory}/eggs/scons-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/

This would work if (2) were on PYTHONPATH and the contents of (4) were copied or linked to the bin directory.

Ideally, I would like to install this as an egg to make use of my global eggs-directory; I don't want to have several copies of the same build tool. Is it possible to accomplish this goal using existing recipes, or should I write my own recipe?

---

EDIT: I made a personal copy and modified SCons' setup.py arguments so that a scons entry point will be created. The only changes I made: remove 'cmdclass', add 'entry_points'.

```
arguments = {
    'name'             : "scons",
 ...
    'scripts'          : scripts,
    'entry_points'     : {
            'console_scripts':
                ['scons = SCons.Script:main']
            }
}
```

This kind of works. It gives me a scons script in bin/scons, but not sconsign, scons-time, or scons.bat. I put it in a tar in /var/www/eggs and serve it with apache.

```
[buildout]
parts = 
    python

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
interpreter = mython
eggs = 
    scons == 2.0.1
find-links = 
    http://localhost/eggs/
```

Not sure if I want to continue in this direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my. I looked into the setup.py for SCons, and it is a bit of a mess. It even stubbornly only installs in `/usr/local` when installing on a Mac. It certainly is not suitable for use with setuptools (and thus zc.buildout).

You can use `zc.recipe.command` to run the setup.py script with `${buildout:executable} setup.py` and configure it to install in a `parts` subdir, then use a separate part to symlink all the scripts into `bin/`:

```
[buildout]
parts = scons

[scons-download]
recipe = gocept.download
url = http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/scons/scons-2.0.1.tar.gz
md5sum = beca648b894cdbf85383fffc79516d18

[scons-install]
recipe = plone.recipe.command
command = ${buildout:executable} ${scons-download:location}/setup.py install --prefix=${buildout:parts-directory}/scons-install
location = ${buildout:parts-directory}/scons-install

[scons]
recipe = cns.recipe.symlink
symlink =
    scons
    scons-time
    sconsign
symlink_base = ${scons-install:location}/bin
symlink_target = ${buildout:bin-directory}
```

So, we ignore setuptools altogether, do not build an egg, but instead just download the tarball, run `setup.py` manually, then symlink the interesting parts.

Comment: That is sufficient for what I need to do. Thanks!